# X-Editor not working

Tags: knockout.js

I have problem with X-Editor.
I would like to make example as below

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: $parent.selectedTab() === $data }">
                <a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr:{href:'#UserTab_'+ID()},click: $parent.selectedTab">
                    <span data-bind="editable:Title, editableOptions: {toggle:'mouseenter',name: 'Title', pk: ID, url: '/updateTitle'}"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-link" data-bind="click:$parent.removeTab">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Where I have link to select the tab and under this link I have my editable span.
The editable span work fine when I move it up to not be under the event of tab selection.

How could make it work? It currently show the edit popup but not accept the new value.

Comment: Some simple jsfiddle would help a lot. It seems that you should play with handling default click action, see notes 3 and 4 in [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

Comment: I know it is something about those points, but could not get solution.
Do you know anyway to debug the editing click event,so may got it from this point

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle, it's hard to tell. This part seems strange: `click: $parent.selectedTab` - what did you want to do here? If you want to assign a new value to selected tab, it should be done in separate handler, or inline: `click: function() { $parent.selectedTab($data); }` or something like that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gherbas/wy5e27t0/

Comment: The editable work in the details part but not working on tab header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event handler somehow interferes with editable binding. To fix this, simply change your click binding as follows:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.selectedTab($data); return true; }">
```

This allows default click action to fire after your click function has completed. For details, see Note 3 in [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/wy5e27t0/1/)